# Set the height of screen to the height of div in CSS

Tags: css, html

I have been working on HTML5, javascript and CSS and i want to get the height of screen and set the height of my "div" accordingly in CSS only without using javascript and jquery.. so that it adjusts itself to any screen.
I've tried using height=100% but it takes the height as long as div's content.
Any idea plzz help me out..

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: can you include some jsfiddle example of what you are trying to do

Comment: you can get the height as `screen.height` it js. you cant do anyway else

Comment: ok. what do you actually want to do?

Comment: This is what i m doing... http://jsfiddle.net/n8sGx/2/  nowi want div with class report to take the height of screen. Please click on login then only u can see the <div class="report"> with 3 buttons "home" "kpi-reporting" ,"epf-reporting" ..

Comment: ok how does this look http://jsfiddle.net/btevfik/n8sGx/3/

Comment: you can remove the borders

Comment: ya a little change in that helped me.. thanks a lot.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Setting height=100% should work - make sure that the containing elements are also set to 100% height, and add position:absolute

Here's a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/C3anM/

```
<div id="wrapper">Test content </div>
```

+

```
#wrapper {
    height:100%;
    background-color:green;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you are trying to absolute position it.

```
div{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/btevfik/DMUcY/

by default the position is static.so the div's are positioned in order and their height is calculated by their content unless you set a `px` value for height.

http://jsfiddle.net/btevfik/MjM9Y/

Answer (score 0):

You have to set:

```
html, body
{
    height: 100%;
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sG8gm/

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be looking for viewport-relative css units. [They're not supported across the board](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units) at the moment, but they are very well-supported among users with modern browsers.

[The spec](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths) defines them as follows:

> **vw unit**
>
> Equal to 1% of the width of the initial containing block.
>
> **vh unit**
>
> Equal to 1% of the height of the initial containing block.
>
> **vmin unit**
>
> Equal to the smaller of ‘vw’ or ‘vh’.
>
> **vmax unit**
>
> Equal to the larger of ‘vw’ or ‘vh’.

Typical percentage-widths size the element relative to the nearest parent, or, in the case with absolute positioning, the closest parent with `position: relative;` whereas viewport-relative lengths will always be calculated relative to.... the viewport, regardless of the parent elements in the tree.